# Android Database Writing error

Tags: android, sqlite

I got an app that as an internal database, and the app crashes with this error :

```
04-30 20:46:30.836    1647-1647/prosis.guiatour E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such column: Basílica_Santa_Luzia
```

and the code that this is refering to is :

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
    Log.e("Database Operations"," Table Created....");
    db.execSQL(addingInfo("Basílica_Santa_Luzia", "Stuff", "10.43597", "-10.5747"));
Log.e("Database Operations"," Data Inserted");
}
public String addingInfo(String nome, String cat, String lat, String longi){
    String Query = "INSERT INTO "+ Table_name+" VALUES("+nome+","+cat+","+lat+","+longi+");";
    return Query;
}
```

And this is my contructer query :

```
private static final String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "+ Contract.NewLocalInfo.Table_name+" ("+ Contract.NewLocalInfo.Nome+" TEXT,"+ Contract.NewLocalInfo.Categoria+" TEXT,"+ Contract.NewLocalInfo.Latitude+" TEXT,"+ Contract.NewLocalInfo.Longitude+" TEXT);";
```

I think the SQL is well Writen so what do you think is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL would not be valid. Based on your function, you would get:

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(Basilica_Santa_Luzia,Stuff,10.43,10.57)
```

which is not valid. You have to single-quote strings like:

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('Basilica_Santa_Luzia','Stuff','10.43','10.57')
```

But, you should not be writing any SQL unless you have complex requirements. You should use what's built into Android or get a third-party option.

Writing an SQL Query string creates security risks and causes errors like this one.
To insert, instead do:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("key","value");
cv.put("key2","value2");
db.insert("table_name",cv);
```

This approach will automatically escape any paramaters and guarantee that your query is not erroneous.

Also, the latitude and longitude probably should not be `String`s. I don't remember for sure, but what I think you need is `double` for the `Java`/`Android` side and in normal SQL, you would need a `decimal` datatype on the column, but its `SQLite` and I'm not sure what you're supposed to do for a decimal column in sqlite, so maybe [Duck it](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sqlite+decimal+column).

Also, I made a [database manager class](http://forum.jakar.co/databasemanager/210233/) which wraps the SQLiteOpenHelper class to ensure synchronization and thread safety, which can simplify your life a ton and prevent tons of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add single quote around all values then this insert will work. Final query should be like below

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES('Basílica_Santa_Luzia','Stuff','10.43597','-10.5747');
```

Comment: This will blow up when a string contains a quote.

Comment: Single quote in value can be parsed by adding one more single quote before it